# How to embed instance method with link_to text field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On erb:

```
@student.count  #--> 4 

  <li><%= link_to "Show All",   'all'   %></li>#-->Show all
```

I want to show

> show All(3)

.

I tried 
`<li><%= link_to "Show All"@students.count,   'all'   %></li>`
or
 `<li><%= link_to "Show All"+@students.count,   'all'   %></li>`

But all didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interpolation

```
<li><%= link_to "Show All(#{@student.count})", 'all' %></li>
```

This doesn't work because you are concatenating a string and a number (TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String)

```
"Show All" + @students.count
```

This works

```
"Show All" + @students.count.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
<li><%= link_to "Show All(" + @students.count.to_s + ")" , 'all' %></li>
```

OR

```
<li><%= link_to "Show All(#{@student.count})", 'all' %></li>
```